# How do I block this gap in door frame gasket/ weather stripping?

Tags: doors, weatherstripping

I found a small gap at the bottom non-hinge corner of my exterior door's weather stripping/ gasket, and found that ants are getting in through it.

The door is very new, I think less than a year old, as is the weather stripping.

Here is the door from the inside:

[image]

And in the lower left corner, just visible in the day due to some light leakage, is a small gap:

[image]

If I push on the door in that corner, the gap can be closed, but it takes probably 20-30 pounds of force:

[image]

Here is a view with the door open:

[image]

And another one:

[image]

From the outside, with the door closed then open, it appears that square beige piece is applying a little pressure to the long white strip gasket that runs vertically, keeping it from contacting the door face for the bottom couple of inches:

[image]

[image]

I don't know why that little square beige piece of weather stripping is there, or whether that's a standard thing.

What are my options for sealing that small gap to keep out ants and drafts?

Should I just remove the square beige gasket, or try to move it towards the inside by a few mm to take the pressure off the white gasket? If the white gasket doesn't spring back after that and close the gap, do I need to replace the entire white gasket or can I tuck a few inches long strip of low-density foam inside the white gasket (I think it's hollow) to puff it back out?

Or should I just put some clear silicone where the beige meets the white to bridge the gap and hope that that does it?

Thanks.

PS: Although I mentioned ants getting in, I'm not looking for help on ant control. Already did lots of research on that, and I'm now putting diatomaceous earth and borax baits around, etc. Also the ants in question are med-large carpenters, so the gap doesn't have to be reduced to zero, just small enough that bigger ants can't easily stroll through.

PPS: I wondered if the door was bent along the bottom edge, but it doesn't appear to be:

[image]